# Why is my "mood cue" not working?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, potentiometer

I am new to Arduino, and I am working through the "Arduino Projects book," with the Arduino Uno. I am working on project 5, "the mood cue." It is basically a potentiometer-controlled servo. I am certain that I have the code for it correct, and certain that I have all the wiring correct. I have the potentiometer value and the angle at which the potentiometer is turned printed on the serial monitor.

I upload the code, and the serial monitor begins printing correctly, changing when I twist the potentiometer. But the servo doesn't move. It lets off a faint buzzing sound, and that is it.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I don't know what I have done wrong. Do you think my servo is broken?

Here is my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;
int const potPin = A0;
int potVal;
int angle;

void setup() {
  myServo. attach(9);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  potVal = analogRead(potPin);
  Serial.print ("potVal:");
  Serial.print (potVal);
  angle = map(potVal, 0, 1023, 0, 179);
  Serial.print ("angle:");
  Serial.print (angle);
  myServo.write (angle);
  delay(15);
}
```

Here is my wiring:
file:///C:/Users/matth_000/Downloads/Arduino%20PotServ.jpg

Comment: Maybe you have your servo wired wrong.  Please post a photograph of your setup.

Comment: Buzzing, non-moving motors usually means not enough voltage and/or current.

Comment: file:///C:/Users/matth_000/Downloads/Arduino%20PotServ.jpg

is not gonna help much...

Answer (score 2):

The classic way of wiring up motors, including servos, is to provide them with separate power. The image below should clarify this:

[image: Wiring for servo motor]

The batteries (in this case) have the sole function of providing power to the servo motor. The "data" pin however goes to the Arduino.

The Arduino itself is powered by the USB cable in this example.

The **important** point is the blue wire - the shared ground wire. Both the Arduino and the servo (and batteries) must have a common ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the components that came in the starter kit, the servo is wired differently in the book than it is in the actual kit.

Make sure the red wire on the servo is connected to the power, the black to the ground and the white to the data. The specs are also written on the side of the servo motor.

In the project book, the wires went into these rows on the breadboard:

26. GND
27. 5V
28. Signal

Whereas for me that meant it was:

26. GND
27. Signal
28. 5V

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to arduino and I had the same problem of the servo buzzing but not moving.  I found the reason was the servo wires came in a different order than what was written in the book.  After correctly connecting the 5v, GND, and Signal by moving a few wires on the bread board things worked as planed.  Hoped this helps.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I had similar behavior with the servo motor in this project. The servo buzzed and either did not move or made very slight erratic movements.

**The problem in my case was that I had wrongly placed the wire that is supposed to connect the potentiometer to pin A0.**

Here's how my board looked *after* I corrected the problem:

[image: my mood cue circuit]